# What is the most efficient method of sending mail to a large number of users in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm using ActionMailer, and my current function is as follows:

```
  def send_profile_reminder()
    User.all do |user|
      if user.setup_profile == false
        ReminderMailer.send_reminder(user).deliver
      end
    end
  end
```

Is this the most efficient answer?

Comment: Define "efficient"

Comment: Efficient in the sense of the fastest (time efficiency) function that would be able to do the mailing task. (At least fast enough to not cause a delay in website performance)

Comment: In terms of not affecting website performance this code is the worst. It will block your page until all mails are delivered (or page times out). Look into sending mails in the background (`.deliver_later`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionMailer is good in sending single emails but it leads to trouble while sending for large users.
Some of the services like [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com)
and [Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/)  will help you in sending bulk emails to large number of users.